# Запрос к местоположению на сайте без js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать запрос к местоположению пользователя зашедшего на сайт, не использую javascript.
Я новичок, не знаю js. Можно ли это сделать например на php?
*Если я несу какой-то бред, скажите, где.*

Comment: Есть `Geolocation API`, для него нужен `JS`, но сам `Api` очень простой.

Comment: Без JS никак не сделаете. Хотя, можете попробовать узнать по IP.